# xrdp and key combinations

Tags: 15.10, virtualization, xrdp, virt-manager

I'm facing an annoying issue and I suspect it's related to the way XRDP manage keys.

I'm running a VMs server which is powered by Xubuntu 15.10. The virtualisation layer is KVM and I installed Virt-Manager for VMs management I can't do on the Kimchi web interface.

Everything runs fine, except when I'm connected to this server through XRDP, and I click the "Send Ctrl+Alt+Del" virt-manager menu item, nothing happens.

Of course, if I'm logged into this server locally, this works.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I have this problem too.... it's weird that even the send keys menu doens't work!  Did you find any solution?

Comment: It also doesn't work for me for X2Go either... but regular X11 forwarding over SSH does work...

Answer (score 0):

I could be a little off-base on some of this, so an adjustment based on information from upstream maintainers of the various projects could be in order.  But this is what I think I've observed:

- When SPICE is used with `virt-manager`, it requires XKB extension in the X server.  If not, virt-manager complains bitterly when run with `--debug` switch. (You get errors like `(virt-manager:121855): vnc-keymap-WARNING **: Unknown keycode mapping '(null)'.`).
- Both tightvncserver and vnc4server X servers in the Ubuntu 16.04 repos are really old and not maintained - I think they are nearly abandoned.  They don't support XKB: `setxkbmap -query` reports that the extension isn't there.

Therefore, I conclude that `virt-manager` isn't compatible with the above VNC servers, at least in its current incarnation.  Fortunately, TightVNC appears to support XKB and seems to work (as evidenced by `setxkbmap -query`).  But it's not in any official Ubuntu repository.  You can get the `.deb` files from here: https://bintray.com/tigervnc/stable/tigervnc/1.6.0#files

As of 2016-05-30 they don't have a released version supporting Ubuntu 16.04.  But you can find some nightly built packages that support it - they worked for me.

If you still have trouble, try installing `x11-xkb-utils` package also.  I had to install this to get X2Go Server working with virt-manager; until then, I was having similar problems.

Once you have TigerVNC installed and set to your default Xvnc server, xrdp should seamlessly use it without any special configuration.

Comment: Thanks James. The x11-xkb-utils us already installed in my server.

Comment: OK, did you try using TigerVNC?

Comment: Not yet, not sure if I'll get the time for this, I'll let you know.